# ReactJS Build returns empty page

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to deploy my React app that I created on Firebase hosting. But the problem is that when I run the `npm run build` command it builds the project correctly but when I open `index.html` it returns empty page. What should I do?

Please, find this empty page here: https://tutorm-db33prg.firebaseapp.com

It seems as it's not importing the main.js file but I don't know if that's the problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looking at the source code for the html page in the link you provided, there's no inclusion of a script tag with your React app javascript file.

Comment: Please specify how you generated your project.

Comment: @nbkhope I just run `npm run build` and then `firebase deploy`

Comment: @nbkhope that is the problem - that it seems to build the app without this script :(

Comment: What package are you using for firebase? Is it a standalone command or an npm package?

Comment: @nbkhope I used `firebase-tools` and then `firebase init`